# How do we install and set up Perforce file explorer, P4vx in WIN server 2019 for perforce depots?

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

How do we install  Perforce file explorer, P4vx in WIN server 2019 for perforce depots? does it require to be installed in master machine or the client from where user access? it is new feature by Perforce version controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perforce is client/server software.  P4V and the Explorer extension are both **client** applications and so they are installed on the machines where users do their work.  The only thing that needs to be installed on the "master machine" is the Perforce **server** application, P4D.